# Как сделать несколько update в одном запросе sql

Tags: php

Нужно сделать вот такой `update` но каждый раз так писать это я так понял не есть хорошо к тому же этих обновлений может бить разное количество.

Так вот как все то что я написал ниже написать в один запрос?

```html
$sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `name`='Категория 1' WHERE `cat`='1'";
$sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `name`='Категория 2' WHERE `cat`='2'";
$sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `name`='Категория 3' WHERE `cat`='3'";
$sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `name`='Категория 4' WHERE `cat`='4'";
```

В основном таких запросов будет не больше 6 но как то в цикле их делать не хочу, боюсь нагрузит сайт :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь о MySql то можно воспользоваться INSERT + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
(2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
(3, 'a3', 'b3', 'c3'),
(4, 'a4', 'b4', 'c4'),
(5, 'a5', 'b5', 'c5'),
(6, 'a6', 'b6', 'c6')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
a=VALUES(a),
b=VALUES(b),
c=VALUES(c);
```

Смысл в том, что если запись уже существует в таблице по primary key, то она обновится данными, которые Вы описали после конструкции ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query)

Answer (score 1):

Вы немножко не понимаете что такое **нагрузка**, отсюда и ваш вопрос.

Попробую доступно донести свое представление:

Сперва надо определиться что мы будем подразумевать под словом **нагрузка**, это либо время обработки (сколько времени потребуется для выполнения запросов) либо объем ресурсов (нагрузка на цп и т.д.). Понятно что эти 2 параметра связаны друг с другом, но поверьте, они не связаны прямой зависимостью, поэтому конкретно сейчас мы их разделим. Т.к. запросы у вас простые апдейты, на объем ресурсов они сильно не ударят, поэтому нас интересует время.

*Время обработки запроса у вас суммируется из двух частей:*

1) Время, которое затрачивает скрипт PHP на **отправку** запроса и на **прием** ответа. **(1)**

2) Время, которое надо самому MySQL серверу для **обработки** вашего запроса и формирования ответа. **(2)**

**К примерам:**

У вас есть цикл с кол-вом итераций например 10, который в теле формирует и отправляет простой запрос (например добавление новой записи). Итого 10 запросов, тут значительное время тратится на **(1)**, т.е. на отправку и на прием ответа. Однако если вы пошлете эти 10 запросов разом, через `;`, то тем самым вы сводите время к минимуму в данной ситуации.

Теперь давайте разберем ситуацию, когда вы делаете `INSERT + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (как вам подсказали выше), и отправкой UPDATE через `;`. Вообще mysql предоставляет инструменты которые позволяют смотреть, на сколько "удачным" вышел ваш запрос, сколько ресурсов он требует, сколько колонок затрагивает и т.д. К гадалке не ходи, но что-то мне подсказывает что первый вариант будет выполняться дольше, ибо так заложено его конструкцией. Собсна используя простой update через `;` вы сократите **(2)**.

**Итого:**

В целом можно сказать что:

**(1)** - это кол-во обращений к БД из скриптов, которые вы делаете, когда пользователь обращается к странице. (чем меньше, тем лучше).

**(2)** - это оптимизация запросов, вот тут уже целая наука, но в вашем случае простой апдейт будет удачным вариантом.

**P.S.** С индексированными запросами MySQL справляется очень хорошо и годно, способен выдержать большие объемы данных и работать с ними достаточно быстро, так что обращайте на это ваше внимание. Проблемы наблюдаются с `JOIN`, `LIKE`, с неиндексированными запросами.

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между `UPDATE ....; UPDATE .....; UPDATE .....;` и `UPDATE .....` `UPDATE .....` `UPDATE .....`

Comment: @Peresada В том, что вы `явно` указываете MySQL-парсеру, где конец запроса, и нет надобности смотреть далее как продолжение запроса.

Comment: @Mantikyl я о другом, если сначала пройтись циклом, чтобы сформировать запросы даже пусть с `;` а потом выполнить его - это будет тоже самое, что делать единичные запросы в самом цикле. И это будет в любом случае медленнее, чем 1 запрос. Попробуйте сами

Comment: @Peresada будет медленнее чем `INSERT + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? P.S. 10 запросов через `;` будет не тоже самое что единичные запросы в цикле по причине (1).

Comment: Да, будет медленнее. Я это на собственной практике проверил. Разумеется это становится заметно на более больших количествах (от 100к)

Comment: @Peresada мне-ж не сложно проверить, я сам не тестил, для меня это было очевидно, но раз вы сказали, пришлось затестить: на `100 000` строк, кол-во тестов `100`, среднее время `INSERT + ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` = `1.21` против `UPDATE ... ; UPDATE ... ; ...` = `0.055`. Если вас интересуют результаты и как я это получил, создайте темку, я вам пришлю исходники.

Answer (score 0):

```
$updateArr = array(
    1 => 'Категория 1'
    2 => 'Категория 2'
    3 => 'Категория 3'
    4 => 'Категория 4'
);

foreach( $updateArr as $categoryId => $categoryName ){
    $sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `name`='".$categoryName."' WHERE `cat`='".$categoryId."'";
    // sql execute
}
```

Ну если в цикле не хотите, то, вам [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255138/sql-update-multiple-records-in-one-query)

Comment: А такой запрос БД нагружать не будет. Я тут на одном форме вычитал что можно вместо INSERT написать REPLACE и как бы это обновить . Как через INSERT сделать вставку я знаю

Comment: @Анатолий множество мелких запросов нагружают бд значительно сильнее, чем один большой. Об этом говорят и сами разработчики СУБД. Так что можете смело действовать через ссылку указанную